# Javascript array.find() callback overrides object to global array

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I have this block of code:

```
wordObj.baseLang.find(function (item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty("Example")) {
            var exTranslation = wordObj.targetLang.filter(function (targetLangItem) {
                if (targetLangItem.id === item.id) return targetLangItem.Example || '';
            });
            var obj=[item.id,wordObj.ID,lid,item.Example,(exTranslation[0] ? exTranslation[0].Example : null)];
            console.log(obj);
            insertquery2[1]=obj;
            batchQueries.push(insertquery2);
        }
    });
```

where: `wordObj` is an object that contains a field `baseLang` which is an array of objects (and some of the objects in this array have the key `Example`). I also have a global array `batchQueries` which will hold subarrays like the one i am trying to create in the above code block. Array `insertquery2` has length 2:

- `insertquery2[0]` has a string such as : `"insert into tablename (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values (?,?,?,?,?)"` and
- `insertquery2[1]` will hold the actual values of the query (this is what the above code tries to do).

My goal is to create arrays of insert queries for the same table. i.e:

```
batchQueries = [
     ["insert into tablename (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values (?,?,?,?,?)",[val1,val2,val3,val4,val5]],         
     ["insert into tablename (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values (?,?,?,?,?)",[val1,val2,val3,val4,val5]],
]
```

(I am limited to this structure of array).

My issue is that if I console.log `obj`, I can get the different values for each item, while adding the object in `insertquery2[1]` and then pushing it to the global array will show only the last item found.

I know that it has to do with pushing by value and callbacks but no matter what I've tried, I can't make it work yet

How can i fill the global array with all the different items that have the property `Example`?

thanks in advance. If you need any further info just ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Javascript always passes by value. However, if you pass an object to a function, the "value" is really a reference to that object, so the function can modify that object's properties but not cause the variable outside the function to point to some other object.

The reason you only see the last item found is because you're overwriting the second index in `insertQuery2` (which is an object) in each iteration and passing it to the `push` function. Thus, `insertquery2[1]=obj;` is modifying the value each time and the last time it's modified is during the last iteration.

Instead of modifying `insertQuery2`, just make a new array:

```
var copyInsertQuery2 = [insertQuery2[0], obj];
```

and push that to `batchQueries` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ll try your suggestion and will post back.

Comment: It works. I did try part/similar things of your suggestion but not a copy of the subarray. Thanks again!